# How to put placeholder text in the main post input area?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, wp-admin, admin-menu

I'm making a course plugin for a university in England. I'm looking to put some default placeholder text in the main post content area, on the admin side. Its the rich text editor I want it to go behind. I might just be typing the wrong words, but can't find it here... preferably a non js thing...

Basically something like 'Use this area to write an introduction to the course...'.

Thanks

Comment: Here ya go: https://github.com/tripflex/wp-tinymce-placeholder

Answer (score 5):

You can change 'post' to which ever post type you want to apply the default content to.

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'wpse57907_default_content', 10, 2 );
function wpse57907_default_content( $content, $post ) {
    if ( 'post' == $post->post_type )
        $content = 'Use this area to write an introduction to the course...';

    return $content;
}
```

---

#### Edit

I'm not sure you *can*  add placeholder text to tinymce editors. The followng method will add a placeholder to the underlying textarea (you can view it on the 'html', soon to be 'text' tab):

```
add_filter('the_editor','wpse57907_add_placeholder');
function wpse57907_add_placeholder( $html ){
    $html = preg_replace('/<textarea/', '<textarea placeholder="my place holder text" ', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

But this does not appear on the visual editor (as I say, I'm not sure placeholders work with TinyMCE - if someone knows how, please comment.).

Comment: Hey Stephen, thanks for quick response that's almost exactly what I'm looking for except do you know any way to make it like placeholder text? So it will disappear as soon as they focus in the field?

Comment: I've updated my answer...

Comment: TinyMCE is an iframe with regular HTML and `contenteditable` if I remember this correct. The only way to let text act like a HTML5 `placeholder` is some (probably fragile) JavaScript.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, the first method does the job anyway, I'm probably being a bit OCD about it. Cheers for the answers :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I adapted it along with a TinyMCE plugin to work with WordPress :)

Answer (score 2):

Based off a placeholder plugin I found for TinyMCE, I adapted it to work for WordPress, and created a repo specifically for it.  Works perfectly for me!

https://github.com/tripflex/wp-tinymce-placeholder

Answer (score 1):

This could be the answer:
http://codepen.io/flesler/pen/AEIFc

Just adding the following CSS will make it work like a placeholder:

```
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    display: block; /* For Firefox */
}
```

We just need to find a way to add a data-attribute to the contenteditable element in the tinyMCE and also add the little bit of CSS to it to affect the content editable.